# Extracting the input value from a mathjax paper-input polymer object

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, mathjax

I am trying to read the value the user inputs into a polymer paper-input object. However, this is a custom object as follows :

```
<dom-module id="mathjax-input">
<template>
   <paper-input  on-input="handleInputChanged" label="{{ label }}" value="{{ formula }}">
   </paper-input>
</template>
```

This is intending to show the user input translated (if it's in LaTeX code) to the equivalent LaTeX result. The following is the input box:

```
<div>
<mathjax-input id="formula" label="Enter formula: " ></mathjax-input>
</div>
```

Assuming now that the "onsubmit" event of the form calls the following function:

```
<script>
function copy_latex(){
                var input = document.getElementById('formula').value                  
                return true;
                }
</script>
```

variable "input" should now get what the user typed. This is not working though. Can you please help me locate the error? 
-Thanks!!

Comment: *assume that for the first paper-input definition the properties are defined, though for shortness I did not include them.

Comment: First problem is you're trying to read a `value` property from the `mathjax-input` element, which doesn't exist (at least not in the template). If you changed `.value` to `.formula` in `copy_latex()`, it would've returned the value of `paper-input`. Note that fetching a value from the element like this is rarely needed. I think you should explore more of Polymer's data binding features to help minimize this type of code.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with:

```
var input = document.querySelector('#formula').formula;
```

Thanks a lot!